# ReactJS token base post?

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I want to send data to the following URL. I send the token I received from Token verification but it gives "Bad request" error. can you help me ?

```
handleSubmit() {
   fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/debt/create',{
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
           Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('id_token')}`,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({
           user: '1',
           customer: '9',
           debtKey: 'b1d9ef1b-45ad-4dc5-80cc-95f7994c0aae',
           createduserKey: '0245abb9-2837-4f37-ae02-9be1b88887ef',
           totalDebt: 789,
           receivedAmount: 115,
           description: 'Debt description',
           paymentDate: '01.01.2019'
       }),
   }).then(response => {
       console.log(response);
       return response.json()
   }).then(json => {
       //this.setState({
       //    user:json
       //});
   });
 console.log("form gönderme ekranına düştü");
}
```

Comment: Can you post code in api?

Comment: Can you try sending body without JSON.stringify?

Comment: are you able to make request through postman ?

Comment: @FatimMzm check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/58217732/8138584

Answer (score 0):

`Authorization` is a `key` .it should be in quotes.

```
headers: {
       'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('id_token')}`,
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
```